# Visual Studio Graphics Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, directx-11

I cant get the Graphical Debugger in **VS 2012 Ultimate** to work, & I have no idea why.

The debugger starts ok, but when I hit the print screen button, the debugger just says its waiting for DX to draw frames. [even after I exit]

I am sure the draw refers to the **Present()** in the swap chain. I am calling it [thats why you see the box down there]

Is there some bug I need to be aware of?

**Edit:**
I think the render target might be related to **OMSetRenderTargets()**.
I called it exactly as the SDK sample did, so I don't know what else to think.

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Are you using windows 8? AFAIK you need to be on Windows 8 for the GPU debugging to work.

Comment: Im on Win7 64bit. The sample codes that come with the SDK works fine. I just cant tell what the difference is [everything] since I coded my DX app myself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer on the Visual Studio graphics diagnostic tools at Microsoft. I'm fairly new on the team, and I don't believe that any previous team members were actively watching Stack Overflow, so sorry about the wait on this question.

As it's been a few months I'm guessing that you might not have the repro around anymore. So such this might be a bit hard to diagnose here and now. From what you shared it looks like the playback engine (which we use to capture and replay DirectX data while the application is running) crash while trying to collect data on your application. Sadly with the first release of our tool (In VS 2012) stability issues of this type are more common then we would like. Simply a function of how we did collection on something as complex as DirectX. However since then, particularly with Update 2, we've made some very big strides with compatibility and stability. As a first step I'd make sure that you have all the VS updates installed as Update 2 was a big upgrade for the graphics diagnostic tools in particular (Preview of 2013 as well if you have access to that).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use PIX instead http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3PISvNTeB0

[PIX Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3PISvNTeB0)